# Kendo Grid Angular - Filter works but Sort does not work

Tags: html, angular, sorting, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have copied the same code from another component, where both filter and sort work. Now I have this (shortened) code:

```
<mat-card class="fng-layoutcard">
  <kendo-grid
    class="fng-table fng-searchable"
    [exampleStoreGridBinding]="adapter"
    [loading]="loading$ | async"
    scrollable="virtual"
    [sortable]="{ allowUnsort: true, mode: 'multiple' }"
    filterable="menu"
    [selectable]="selectableSettings"
    (contentScroll)="contentScroll($event)"
    #kendoGridInstance="kendoGrid"
  >
    <kendo-grid-column field="status" title="Status" [sortable]="true">
      <ng-template
        kendoGridFilterMenuTemplate
        let-column="column"
        let-filter="filter"
        let-filterService="filterService"
      >
        <sh-util-kendo-grid-column-string-search
          [column]="column"
          [filter]="filter"
          [filterService]="filterService"
        ></sh-util-kendo-grid-column-string-search>
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>

    <sh-util-kendo-grid-custom-messages> </sh-util-kendo-grid-custom-messages>
    <kendo-grid-messages
      noRecords="Keine Datensätze verfügbar."
    ></kendo-grid-messages>
  </kendo-grid>
</mat-card>
```

The filter works, the sort **controls** work also, but no sort is happening. The value is just a simple string. Does anobody know what I did wrong?

Comment: but if I change [sortable] in kendo-grid to [sortable]="true", it works, but then I cant use multiple sort anymore